# Recommendations for an Inquiry request cart/form system

Tags: looking-for-a-script, shopping-cart

Here is the goal:

Site visitor sees things they like while browsing the site. Visitor click desired item to generate equivalent of 'add to cart'. They 'check out' but there is no transaction just a from generates and email inquiry which they add their contact and additional notes to and review / remove items. Server sends email to predefined recipient and CC client

So basically it's a form with additional items appended to it from the browsing session.

Other Details:

No user login required

Quote request sends server generated email

Ability to easily add new items to inventory - I want to build a database of inventory like a store but there would never be any check out just the generation of a request form.

PHP/mysql solutions preferred
Wordpress solution o.k.
joomla solution o.k.

Answer (score 2):

I guess almost any shopping-cart system will do. It should be quite trivial to skip the payment step in the process. Removing functionality is usually easier than adding.